# join word + apostrophe + s to maintain possessive form of word

Tags: python

```
text = ['This', 'brand', 'she', 'quenched', 'in', 'a', 'cool', 'well', 'by', 'Which', 'from', 'Love', "'", 's', 'fire']
```

When I do a `' '.join(text)` I get the result;

"This brand she quenched in a cool well by Which from Love ' s fire"

I would like to join "Love ' s" as "Love's" instead of separating them. How can I do that along with the `' '.join(text)`?

Comment: You can't. You have to concatenate the `love` `'` and `s` before, so that there is a `love's` item in your list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run a replace after joining. (Replace `" ' "` with `"'"`)

```
' '.join(text).replace(" ' ", "'")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        import re
        print re.sub(r"\s\'\s","'",' '.join(text))
```

You can use this as a hack.It would be tough to join contents of list by 2 conditions.